# Slow networking on Bluemix CF Python app for scraping

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I deployed the basic "Hello World" app on Bluemix. I wanted to deploy my scraper on a fast network so I chose bluemix expecting it to be considerably fast. To test the network speed of bluemix, I put a timer to analyze the time it took bluemix to process a simple request.

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

For this, contrary to my expectation, it took a whole 5-6 secs and occasionally did in 2 secs which was the fastest it did. This is even slower than my current network. Is there a setting that I overlooked?

Edit: Added more info

I am using the 30-days free trial of IBM-Bluemix. And the site I am using is
www.flipkart.com which is an e-commerce site.

Also, I made the app in python runtime with Cloud Foundary.

Comment: Which Bluemix location are you using, are you on a paid or free account, what website are you testing with...?

Comment: Updated with further details.